# dhcpd: any way to check dhcp pool status?

Tags: dhcp

Once `dhcpd` (IPv4) is started, is there any way to check its internal pool status? e.g how many addresses are available?

I checked `man(8) dhcpd`, there's no signals/files available for that info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Ubuntu there is the file `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases`, but it is rather verbose and you probably need a little script if you want more high level statistics. I am unaware of existing tools to do this.

There is a separate man page for this file `man dhcpd.leases` describing the database format.

Comment: Thanks for the filename , on arch linux I find it was located at `/var/state/dhcp/dhcpd.leases`

Comment: On X random linux distro, the location of the lease file is probably defined in the dhcpd.conf file.  It might possibly use the compiled-in default though.     The config file usually lives under /etc (although perhaps in a subdirectory; red hat puts it in /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf).

Comment: @DanPritts The parameter is called `lease-file-name` in `dhcpd.conf` IIRC.

Answer (score 8):

Checking status of leases is easiest with analysis tool.

http://dhcpd-pools.sourceforge.net/

After building the `dhcpd-pools`, you can use `dhcpd.conf` and `dhcpd.leases` as inputs to the command `./dhcpd-pools`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good command to show dhcp leases in nice format.

Check it out:
[Command to list assigned dhcp addresses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91799/command-to-list-assigned-dhcp-addresses/247514#247514)