# File for assigned inet addresses

Tags: files

I am using Lubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.19 and can't find file where are inet addresses stored (etc. 192.168.1.11). Man page for `ifconfig` state files:

```
/proc/net/socket #can't find at all
/proc/net/dev
/proc/net/if_inet6
```

unfortunately nor in any of those are useful informations.

I found something in `/proc/net/fib_trie` but is it place ifconfig parsing from?

EDIT: Address is set by `DHCP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DHCP assigned IP addresses are dynamic (the client contacts the server regularly to ask for a new one, which most of the time is just the same, even the same as you got the last round if it hasn't been reused in the meantime).

As a result, it makes no sense to keep this information in a file, it is just set for the interface, and reset if needed.

Comment: ...and this is where I continue ["command to list assigned dhcp addresses"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91799/command-to-list-assigned-dhcp-addresses)